# setTimeout() in javascript is stop working whenever I switch to new Tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

calling function recursively by setTimeout() will works fine but whenever I shift to new tab setTimeout() stops calling function ?

Comment: JS stops executing when not on focus.

Comment: but why not in case of setInterval() ? It is working fine even after switching to another tab .